Unable to create Project in VS22 with template Angular and ASP.Net Core
My global angular CLI version is 12.1.0. One of the Repo I cloned locally has Angular CLI version 11.0.5. I tried to create project with Angular and ASP.Net Core template in VS2022, using asp.net core version 6.0, 7.0, 8.0. But, none on them are working to create object. Mentioned path 'C:#############\source\repos\trial' in image has angular CLI version 12.1.0.


try running this: npm install -g @angular/cli@latest  (for latest version of angular, replace latest with specific version if you want an older version)  When the project runs ng new your_project_name, it should install the local cli version.

if that fails, you'll want to re-install node first: https://nodejs.org/en
